# Derivative of square root

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What would be the derivative of square roots? For example if I have $2 \sqrt{x}$ or $\sqrt{x}$.

I'm unsure how to find the derivative of these and include them especially in something like implicit.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

$\sqrt x=x^{1/2}$, so you just use the power rule: the derivative is $\frac12x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: what about something like $2\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @soniccool: The derivative of $2f(x)$ is always twice the derivative of $f(x)$.  So the derivative of $2\sqrt x$ is $2\cdot\frac12x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Ah alright i got it

Comment: So why does $2\sqrt{x}$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: @soniccool: You mean $\left(2\sqrt x\right)'=\frac1{\sqrt x}$. For the same reason that the derivative of $2x^3$ is $6x^2$: the derivative of $af(x)$ is $af'(x)$. In this case you have the derivative of $2x^{1/2}$, which is $$2\left(x^{1/2}\right)'=2\cdot\frac12x^{-1/2}=x^{-1/2}=\frac1{\sqrt x}\;.$$

Comment: Okay i get it so basically you bring out the 2 and then 2 becomes 0 right?

Comment: So would $4\sqrt{x}$ be the same thing?

Comment: Yes.

Let $$y = 4\sqrt{x}$$

$$y' = 4(\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x})$$

$$y' = 4\cdot  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

$$y' = \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} $$

Comment: @soniccool: The $2$ does not become $0$. Do you mean that if you differentiate $2x^{1/2}$ as a product, you get $2\cdot\frac12x^{-1/2}+0\cdot x^{1/2}$? That’s true, and you **can** differentiate $2x^{1/2}$ as a product if you really want to, but it’s making unnecessary work for yourself. Don’t make things hard for yourself: use the fact that for any constant $a$ and any differentiable function $f(x)$, $\left(af(x)\right)'=af'(x)$.

Comment: AH okay im an idiot i got it.

Comment: @soniccool: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 59):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, then $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x}}{h} \times \dfrac{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x+h-x}{h (\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x})}\\ = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{h}{h (\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x})} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac1{(\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x})} = \dfrac1{2\sqrt{x}}$$
In general, you can use the fact that if $f(x) = x^{t}$, then $f'(x) = tx^{t-1}$.

Taking $t=1/2$, gives us that $f'(x) = \dfrac12 x^{-1/2}$, which is the same as we obtained above.

Also, recall that $\dfrac{d (c f(x))}{dx} = c \dfrac{df(x)}{dx}$. Hence, you can pull out the constant and then differentiate it.

Comment: This is the best answer here, because it doesn't assume that the power rule (which is easy to prove when the exponent is a positive integer) automatically applies when the exponent is NOT a positive integer.

Answer (score 19):

Another possibility to find the derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is to use geometry. Imagine a square with side length $\sqrt x$. Then the area of the square is $x$. Now, let's extend the square on both sides by a small amount, $d\sqrt x$. The new area added to the square is:
$$dx=d\sqrt x \times \sqrt x + d\sqrt x \times \sqrt x + d\sqrt x^2.$$

[image]

This is the sum of the sub-areas added on each side of the square (the orange areas in the picture above). The last term in the equation above is very small and can be neglected. Thus:

$$dx=2\times d\sqrt x \times \sqrt x$$

$$\frac{dx}{d\sqrt x}=2 \times \sqrt x$$

$$\frac{d\sqrt x}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\times\sqrt x}$$

(To go from the second step to the last, *flip* the fractions on both sides of the equation.)

**Reference:** [Essence of Calculus, Chapter 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0_qX4VJhMQ)

Comment: Nice! I came from the same source i.e 3Blue1Brown's Essense of Calculus series. But do we get any geometric interpretation as such as in the case of `x^2` function? This feels more like an algebraic manipulation that leads to the same value.

Comment: In essence, this approach can serve as a basis to prove the product rule in general

Comment: I kinda feel bad about "The last term in the equation above is very small and can be neglected." 

Because we only have dx approaches to zero, instead of d(x^1/2)]

Answer (score 9):

The Power Rule says that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^\alpha=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$. Applying this to $\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac12}$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sqrt{x}
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^{\frac12}\\
&=\frac12x^{-\frac12}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
However, if you are uncomfortable applying the Power Rule to a fractional power, consider applying implicit differentiation to
$$
\begin{align}
y&=\sqrt{x}\\
y^2&=x\\
2y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}&=1\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}&=\frac{1}{2y}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x) =  \sqrt{x} = x^{1/2}$.

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} x ^{-1/2}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2x^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

If you post the specific implicit differentiation problem, it may help. The general guideline of writing the square root as a fractional power and then using the power and chain rule appropriately should be fine however. Also, remember that you can simply pull out a constant when dealing with derivatives - see below.

If $g(x) = 2\sqrt{x} = 2x^{1/2}$. Then,

$$g'(x) = 2\cdot\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}$$

$$g'(x) = \frac{1}{x^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 4):

Use the product rule $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ and take $f=\sqrt{x}=g$. Then
$$x'=1=(\sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{x})'=(\sqrt{x})'\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x})'=2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x})'.$$
It follows that $$(\sqrt{x})'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: What a cool proof!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

$\sqrt{x}$
Let $f(u)=u^{1/2}$ and $u=x$
That's 
$\frac{df}{du}=\frac{1}{2}u^{-1/2}$ and $\frac{du}{dx}=1$
But, by the chain rule 
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{df}{du}•\frac{du}{dx}
=\frac{1}{2}u^{-1/2} •1
=\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}$
Finally
$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Did you read this before posting it?

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry i don't know when posted it but, here is my answer   \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}$$