# How to differentiate expressions with square roots and division

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having trouble working out how to differentiate expressions that have both division and square roots in them such as:

$$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+7}}$$

if someone could show me the necessary process that would be great.

Comment: Use $$\bigg(\frac{u}{v}\bigg)' = \frac{vu' - uv'}{v^2}$$

Comment: sorry but could you explain that formula for me?

Comment: The $'$ represents the derivative. Here consider $u = 2x$ and $v = \sqrt{x^2+7}$, find their derivatives and substitute in the above formula. Also apply chain rule for $v'$, so that $v' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+7}}\cdot(2x)$

Comment: It's the [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) for derivatives

Comment: I got this :  $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+7}*2-2x*\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+7}}}{\sqrt{x^2+7}}$$. I'm not sure if this is even correct but what do I do from here to reach the final derivative?

Comment: There are 2 mistakes. $u= 2x \implies u' = 2$(correct) and $$v = \sqrt{x^2+7} \implies v' = \frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+7}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+7}}$$. Also, $v^2 = x^2+7$. So, $$(u/v)' = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+7}\cdot2 - 2x\frac{\color{red}{x}}{\sqrt{x^2+7}}}{\color{red}{x^2+7}} = \frac{2(x^2+7)-2x^2}{(x^2+7)\sqrt{x^2+7}}$$ Can you complete now?

Comment: Do I just need to further simplify?

Comment: This is virtually the same as these two questions that were asked (and closed) yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260661/differentiating-expressions-with-division-in-them, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260587/how-to-differentiate-functions-with-square-roots

Answer (score 1):

Using the quotent rule $\bigg(\frac{u}{v}\bigg)' = \frac{vu' - v'u}{v^2}$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+7}}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+7} \cdot (2x)^{'}-2x\cdot {(\sqrt{x^2+7})^{'}}}{(\sqrt{x^2+7})^2}$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+7} \cdot 2 - 2x\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+7}}\cdot(2x) }{x^2+7}=\frac{2\sqrt{x^2+7}-\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+7}}}{x^2+7}=\frac{\frac{2(x^2+7)-2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+7}}}{x^2+7}=\boxed{\frac{14}{(x^2+7)\sqrt{x^2+7}}}$$

Comment: You should have $u = 2x$ and $v = \sqrt{x^2 + 7}$.  You reversed these in your numerator, so your derivative has the wrong sign.

Comment: fixed. Thanks, @N.F.Taussig :-)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problems where you have products, quotients and powers, logarithmic differentiation makes life easier.

Making the problem more general, consider
$$f(x)=\frac{[g(x)]^a}{[h(x)]^b}\implies \log(f(x))=a  \log(g(x))-b \log(h(x))$$ Differnetiate both sides to get
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=a\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}-b\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)}\implies f'(x)=f(x)\Big(a\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}-b\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)} \Big)$$ and simplify to finally obtain
$$f'(x)=a g(x)^{a-1} h(x)^{-b} g'(x)-b g(x)^a h(x)^{-b-1} h'(x)$$